# How can I get my row that is most exact be the first one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a search field where user search in this case "RG Transport".
I want the most exact matches first.

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department.bold_id, 
                departmentid + ' ' + organization.name + ' - ' 
                + department.name AS DisplayValue, 
                organization.name 
FROM   organization, 
       department 
WHERE  organization.bold_id = department.organization 
       AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]%RG%]%' 
       AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]%TRANSPORT%]%' 
ORDER  BY organization.name
```

"RG Transport AB" is on row 78. So I want it to be on first row.
I then try with union

```
SELECT DISTINCT department.bold_id, departmentid + ' ' + organization.name + ' - ' + department.name AS DisplayValue, 
organization.name  FROM Department, Organization
WHERE organization.bold_id = department.organization 
AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]RG TRANSPORT%]%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT department.bold_id, 
                departmentid + ' ' + organization.name + ' - ' 
                + department.name AS DisplayValue, 
                organization.name 
FROM   organization, 
       department 
WHERE  organization.bold_id = department.organization 
       AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]%RG%]%' 
       AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]%TRANSPORT%]%'
```

It works fine but then the following rows are not sorted on name.
If I add

ORDER  BY organization.name

to the last query the first row is lost.
Is there any other way I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

simply add a column with 1 in the top half of the union and a column with 2 in the bottom half

your order by then becomes

```
order by newcolumn, organization.name
```

it is likely that you query may return the company twice however

so perhaps something along these lines may be more relevant

```
SELECT weakMatch.bold_id,
   weakMatch.displayvalue,
   weakMatch.name
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT department.bold_id,
                    departmentid + ' ' + organization.name + ' - '
                    + department.name AS DisplayValue,
                    organization.name
    FROM   department,
           organization
    WHERE  organization.bold_id = department.organization
           AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]RG TRANSPORT%]%') AS
   directMatch
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT department.bold_id,
                                    departmentid + ' ' + organization.name +
                                    ' - '
                                    + department.name AS DisplayValue,
                                    organization.name
                    FROM   organization,
                           department
                    WHERE  organization.bold_id = department.organization
                           AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE '%[[]%RG%]%'
                           AND Upper(searchkeysname) LIKE
                               '%[[]%TRANSPORT%]%') AS
          weakMatch
                ON weakMatch.bold_id = directMatch.bold_id
ORDER  BY directMatch.name,
      weakMatch.name
```

although this assumes a directmatch is always found within a weakmatch

Comment: Your query with join result in 1 row, the exact match of RG Transport. I am definitely not good at SQL, but where is the new column added ?
And no I cannot assume that a direct match is always found.